# Do we have entanglement measure in continuous variables (Not witness)?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, entropy, quantum-entanglement, density-operator

I have been searching for entanglement measures for continuous variable systems like we have entanglement entropy for discrete variable systems. My searches have ended in [entanglement witnesses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entanglement_witness). I was wondering if there are any measures being used in the literature or if I am misunderstanding the use of 'witnesses'.

Comment: For Gaussian states: Robustness of entanglement.